# Re Continuing reading the Quran

Tags: quran

I started reading sourah Youssef today at night, it got too light and I stopped in the middle of the sourah, If I want to continue tomorrow, do I have to restart from the beginning or continue where I stopped last time???

Answer (score 2):

In the name of Allah
There is nothing wrong with reading a surah from the middle of it. So you don't have to restart.